# Can sudo command only be used in ubuntu?

Tags: sudo

This is a curious question only.

Does anybody know if other distributions need sudo to login as root.

The reason I am asking is because I have Virtualbox installed in my ubuntu desktop and I have several other distros.

Comment: **Question needs to be better worded:** *You don't need **sudo** to 'login as root', but rather you use it instead.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. Centos, Debian, and almost every other distro you know has `sudo`. Some doesn't have `sudo` but has `su` (e.g. Android). Not sure about Arch Linux. I remember downloading `sudo` manually.

Refer to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48553/95782) for a bit more detail. It basically says that distros made after mid-2000s will most probably have sudo.

Comment: Arch Linux lets you do what you want when installing, so `sudo` is entirely up to the user to set up.

Comment: @muru Exactly..

Answer (score 6):

No, `sudo` is **not** Ubuntu specific command/package.

By default, many distros come with `sudo` package preinstalled, if not it should be available in the repository so that the user can install it later easily.

Comment: Arch Linux is a prime example - by default there was only root user and `sudo` had to be installed form the AUR repositories

Comment: @Serg yeah..Debian too now-a-days :)

Comment: I haven't tried Debian yet, so it's nice to know what to expect. What about `pkexec` ? or su ? Was it there by default ?

Comment: @Serg `su` was there..can't remember checking `pkexec`, need to check..

Answer (score 3):

`sudo` comes with a lot of distributions, however there are exceptions to the rule. Typically, very minimalistic distros such as Arch Linux come only with root login. Digital Ocean server for me came with root account only, but sudo was there for other users. If it's not there, check for `su` and `pkexec` with `which <command-name>`. These two commands are an alternative to sudo and gksu, and often `pkexec` is preferred over sudo